# [__NSCFType reactToAppEnteringBackground]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, selector, unrecognized-selector

```
-[__NSCFType reactToAppEnteringBackground]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm looking at our crash logs and i got quite a few of `reactToAppEnteringbackground`crashes. I'm not familiar with this function. I'm pretty sure we don't have  a function like this in our app unless it's one of NSObject's? Basically, I couldn't get anything from the crash log to help me as I'm not able to symbolicate it. But, is anyone familiar with this crash? When does it usually happen?

UPDATE:
So i was able to symbolicate. And it led me to `[VungleSDK appDidEnterBackground]`. Basically, it's an external source crash. I've updated my Vungle SDK and hopefully the crash won't happen again.

Comment: This is an User Defined function, you must have defined it anywhere, search with `cmd+shift+f` and enter the function name `reactToAppEnteringBackground `.

Comment: @iphonic I was able to find a way to symbolicate. It pointed to [VungleSDK appDidEnterBackground] function. Maybe they have a call to that function inside. It's a Vungle crash.

Comment: It is usually a symptom of a message being sent to an object that has been released - NSCFType is an internal type